# How can I parse part of html inside the docx document using Java?

Tags: java, html, docx

Story is abit complicated but it boils down to:

Current working code can't print document to the docx correctly - it ignores tables, instead it currently writes each new cell as a new paragraph.

I can access resulting *.docx file before sending it to the user and modify it. That is pretty much only one hook I have.

I managed to imbed html instead of the content that contains my table inside of the document:
[pic. Html inside the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAVws.png)

This html code is pretty much a single string. Example contains just one table, but there can be several tables split by text paragraphs of different formatting, horizontal rules `<hr>`.

What are my options? Any libraries to look into?

ps. Html code from document:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td height="20"><font size="4">n/a</font></td>
    <td height="20"><font size="4">Column1</font></td>
    <td height="20"><font size="4">Column2</font></td>
    <td height="20"><font size="4">Column3</font></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td height="20"><font size="4">Row1</font></td>
    <td height="20"><font size="4">Text123</font></td>
    <td height="20">Text123 </td><td height="20">Text123 </td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td height="20"><font size="4">Row2</font></td>
    <td height="20"><span style="font-size: large;">Text123</span></td>
    <td height="20">Text123 </td>
    <td height="20"><span style="font-size: large;">Text123</span></td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use JSoup after reading HTML then rebuild it with Apache POI or docx4j